# Complex function with difference arguments as ratio identity

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose I have an unknown function $f(z)$ depending on a complex variable $z$. I want to find the quotient between two of these functions so that the resulting function is only a function of the difference between arguments, that is, given two copies $f(z_1),f(z_2)$ with $z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{C}$:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{f(z_1)}{f(z_2)}=F(z_1-z_2).
\end{eqnarray}
An obvious choice is to use the exponential functions:
\begin{eqnarray}
f(z)=e^{z}\to \frac{f(z_1)}{f(z_2)}=e^{z_1-z_2}.
\end{eqnarray}
The question is if there is a way to determine other functional forms of the functions $f(z)$ that could give another form of $F(z_1-z_2)\neq e^{z_1-z_2}$, different from the exponential form written above, and how to determine the form of $f(z)$ in such cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous, one can prove that $f$ is more or less the exponential, while there are lots of examples of discontinuous functions.

First let's write the equation as  $f(z)=F(z-w)f(w)$ and note that if there is $f(w)=0$ then $f(z)=0$ for all $z$ so assume $f$ never vanishes; then if $f$ continuous, there is $g$ continuous st $f=e^g$ (this requires proof but it is easily done locally and then a homotopy and simple connectedness argument show that the result holds on any simply connected domain, in particular in the plane). Same of course for $F=e^h$

So we get $e^{g(z)-g(w)}=e^{h(z-w)}$ or $g(z)-g(w)=h(z-w)+2k(z,w)i$ with $k(z,w)$ continuous in both arguments and taking integral values so constant, hence $$g(z)-g(w)=h(z-w)+2\pi ik$$

Now $g(z)=h(z)+2\pi ik+g(0)$ so $h(z-w)+2\pi ik=g(z-w)-g(0)$ so $g(z)-g(w)=g(z-w)-g(0)$ and changing $g \to g(z)-g(0)$ gives an additive continuous function on $\mathbb C$ which as usual is determined by $g(0)=a, g(i)=b$ as $g(z)=g(x+iy)=xg(1)+yg(i)=ax+by=cz+d\bar z$

(first on $x,y$ integral, then rationals and then real by continuity)

So in general $g(z)=cz+d\bar z+k$ and $f(z)=Ke^{cz+d\bar z}$

In the discontinuous case, take $g$ any discontinuous complex additive function (which can be easily constructed taking rational values only) by taking a base of $\mathbb C$ over $Q$ and note that $e^g$ works, so there are lots and lots of examples,

Comment: +1 nice, more complete than my answer

Answer (score 1):

Let’s rewrite the identity multiplicatively to avoid division issues: $f(z_1)=f(z_2)F(z_1-z_2)$. Plugging in $z_2=0$ implies $f=f(0)F$, i.e the two functions are related by a constant multiple. If $f(0)=0$, this implies $f=0$ identically. If $f(0)\neq 0$, then the function $F=\frac{f}{f(0)}$ satisfies $F(0)=1$ and
\begin{align}
F(z_1)=\frac{f(z_1)}{f(0)}=\frac{f(z_2)F(z_1-z_2)}{f(0)}=F(z_2)F(z_1-z_2),
\end{align}
or writing it slightly differently, $F(a+b)=F(a)F(b)$ for all $a,b\in\Bbb{C}$ (plug in $z_1=a+b$ and $z_2=b$ above). So, we’re looking for all functions $F:\Bbb{C}\to\Bbb{C}$ such that $F(0)=1$ and such that the functional equation $F(a+b)=F(a)F(b)$ is satisfied. If you now assume that $F$ is differentiable at the origin, then you can prove $F$ is in fact differentiable everywhere, and that $F’(z)=F’(0)F(z)$ everywhere, which has the unique solution $F(z)=F(0)e^{F’(0)z}=e^{F’(0)z}$. So, you’re back to an exponential if assume just a bit of regularity.